# Example Jest Unit test for a Wrapper Function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I decided to wrap a imported function over a more generic one, as I will probably use it in more than one place. How would one write a unit test that covers this piece of code entirely?

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const signIn = (
  username,
  password,
  successCallback,
  errorCallback,
) => {
  Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(user => successCallback(user))
    .catch(err => errorCallback(err));
};

export default signIn;
```

I'm using Jest.

I've tried something like this:

```
import signIn from './shared';

test('signIn() executes', () => {
  const success = jest.fn(console.log('good!'));
  const fail = jest.fn(console.log('bad!'));

  signIn('john', 'snow', success, fail);

  expect(fail).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But I must not be understanding either mocks or spying properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this would suit your needs, but there's a builtin to do something similar to what you're doing. https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_callbackify_original

Comment: It definitely could, but I am trying to get 100% coverage, so I'd still have to test my code against that particular function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably test it with something like this. Just stub out the dependencies so you can control everything.

```
import signIn from './shared';
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
describe("signIn", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });
    it("invokes the success callback on success", done => {
        const mockUser = {username: "bob", password: "password"};
        // pretend that everything went great, and give back our mock user
        jest.spyOn(Auth, "signIn").mockImplementation((a, b) => {
            return Promise.resolve(mockUser);
        });
        const mockSuccessCb = (user) => {
            expect(user).toBe(mockUser);
            done();
        };
        const mockErrorCb = (err) => {
            // fail the test if this callback is invoked.
            done(err);
        };
        signIn("bob","tom", mockSuccessCb, mockErrorCb);
    });
});
```

I haven't run any of this, but I think the general idea would work. Doing the error test would be very similar.

Comment: I added a second test with ```.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(mockUser));``` to handle the error case, 100% achieved, thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to have full full coverage, you'd probably want to verify that `Auth.signIn` was `calledWith("bob", "tom")` as well, or make the mock implementation more realistic. These tests pass if you completely ignore the incoming args in the implementation.